# Can't get Javascript function to work in a demo

Tags: javascript

```
function trim(str,options){
  var   string = str.replace(/^\s\s*/, ''),
        ws = /\s/,
        i = str.length,
        j = -1;
  if(options==="begin"){while(ws.test(string.charAt(++j)));return string.slice(j,i);}
  if(options==="end"){while(ws.test(string.charAt(--i)));return string.slice(j+1,i+1);}
  while(ws.test(string.charAt(--i)));while(ws.test(string.charAt(++j)));
  return string.slice(j, i + 1);
}
```

This function is an implementation of the Trim() method that you find in C#.

I've added options for removing withspace both at the beginning and end. The problem is, I can't get it to work in a demo.

What I've done is this:

```
var a = "           zareaerar  arzare        ";
var b = "aezze          azeze      a    ";
var c = "azrazza rzrzrzrp"
var d = " aezzaeazeazeaz         azez ";

document.write('<p style="backround:#ff0000">',trim(a,"begin"),'</p>','<br />');
document.write('<p style="backround:#ff0000">',trim(b,"begin"),'</p>','<br />');
document.write('<p style="backround:#ff0000">',trim(c,"begin"),'</p>','<br />');
document.write('<p style="backround:#ff0000">',trim(d,"begin"),'</p>','<br />');
```

First of all, no background-color appears and the strings also seem to loose the spaces in the middle of the string...

Does this work with user-input only? Are strings automatically trimmed these days?

Comment: What should the Trim() function do? If only remove spaces from end and begging it is overcomplicated 10 times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) You are not seeing a background since you have a typo: `backround` instead of `background`

2) In HTML there is no significance for more than one whitespace. You need to use `&nbsp;` if you want to insert a non-breaking whitespace between words in a paragraph.

[Reference (W3 spec)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1):

> Note that a sequence of white spaces
>   between words in the source document
>   may result in an entirely different
>   rendered inter-word spacing (except in
>   the case of the PRE element). **In
>   particular, user agents should
>   collapse input white space sequences
>   when producing output inter-word
>   space**. This can and should be done
>   even in the absence of language
>   information (from the lang attribute,
>   the HTTP "Content-Language" header
>   field (see [RFC2616], section 14.12),
>   user agent settings, etc.).
>
> The PRE element is used for
>   preformatted text, where white space
>   is significant.

Comment: Yeah, you know what? I've never had that problem before I've never needed to use &nbsp; so long as the words were between quotes...

Comment: @baeltazor: I seriously doubt that as well. Unless you are serving your context as "text/plain" there should be no *visible* difference between "  " (two spaces) and " " (single space) in the output. Quoting is immaterial.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not the answer to your question but why is your `trim` function so complicated?

You can just do:

```
function trim(str, option) {
    if (option === "begin") return str.replace(/^\s+/,"");
    if (option === "end") return str.replace(/\s+$/,"");

    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

If you are using regular expression tests anyway, you might as well just replace all the whitespaces with the `replace` method.

Note: Code adapted from [here](http://www.somacon.com/p355.php).